# Scheduled WebJob

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I'm creating a new Azure WebJob project -- which appears to be a polished version of a console app that can run as a web job.

I want this job to run based on a schedule but in the `Main()` method -- see below -- Microsoft gives you the `host.RunAndBlock()` for the job to run continuously.

Do I need to change that if I want the job to run at regularly scheduled intervals?

```cs
static void Main()
{
    var host = new JobHost();

    // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
    host.RunAndBlock();
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

When using the Azure WebJobs SDK you can use `TimerTrigger` to declare job functions that run on a schedule. For example here's a function that runs immediately on startup, then every two hours thereafter:

```cs
public static void StartupJob(
[TimerTrigger("0 0 */2 * * *", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo timerInfo)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Timer job fired!");
}
```

You can get `TimerTrigger` and other extensions by installing the [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions/) nuget package. More information on `TimerTrigger` and the other extensions in that package and how to use them can be found in the [azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions). When using the `TimerTrigger`, be sure to add a call to `config.UseTimers()` to your startup code to register the extension.

When using the Azure WebJobs SDK, you deploy your code to a **Continuous** WebJob, with **AlwaysOn** enabled. You can then add however many scheduled functions you desire in that WebJob.

Answer (score 5):

An easy way to trigger a WebJob on a schedule would be to code it as a regular console application, and just add a 'settings.job' with the cron based scheduling configuration to the project.
For example, the following definition would trigger it every 5 minutes:

```
{
  "schedule": "0 */5 * * * *"
}
```

No need to use JobHost, just make sure your WebApp is configured as 'Always On'.
You should then deploy the job as a triggered WebJob.

Comment: I second this as the better approach since it's completely agnostic to your WebJob binary (i.e. you could time trigger a C++ binary written 14 years ago with zero modification) -- https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Web-Jobs#scheduling-a-triggered-webjob

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways that I know of for scheduling a web job instead of making it run continiously:

1. Create a scheduled WebJob using a CRON expression
2. Create a scheduled WebJob using the Azure Scheduler

You can find the documentation for both ways on [azure.microsoft.com](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/)

I think you need  `RunAndBlock` in case of Scheduled or Continuous but you can remove it if you have your job as on-demand

Comment: [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web- jobs/) appears to be broken

Comment: @NigelBelham Updated the link, thanks for the heads up